# FloatingActionButton is in the wrong place

Tags: android, xml, webview, widget, floating-action-button

In my xml file I am implementing Floating Action Button. It is supposed to be in the bottom right, but when I run my app it is displaying in the upper left. What is wrong with it? In my xml file it is declared that FAB orientation is bottom | end. Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        ></WebView>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/contacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        app:backgroundTint="#000000"
        />



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_below="@id/contacts"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        app:backgroundTint="#000000"
        />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/contacts"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/home"
        app:backgroundTint="#000000"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#000000"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/home"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
    app:backgroundTint="#000000"
    />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    app:backgroundTint="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```